# How to change the custom OnOff Toggle Button Width and Height at same time in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, togglebutton

I have a custom onoff toggle button style. If user change the toggle button height and width the inside ellipse(Please refer ForegroundEllipse) also change. When I set toggle button Width=50 and Height=25, the ForegroundEllipse width and height is 15. My requirement is when I change the width and height of the toggle button the ForegroundEllipse width and Height will be change. I have used converter for changing the Foreground ellipse with ration calculation. But it is not helps to me. Please anybody help me to done this, My converter is mentioned below, but that is not referred in style now. I have attached the Toggle Button design screenshot please refer,

**ToggleButtonStyle**

```
  <Style x:Key="OnOffToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">       

        <Style.Resources>
            <Color x:Key="Color.Additional.LightGrey">#FFFFFF</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Color.Additional.MediumGrey">#61656B</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Color.MedtronicBranding.MedtronicBlue">#FFFFFF</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Color.MedtronicBranding.CobaltBlue">#14BBA0</Color>

            <Style x:Key="ToggleButtonContentTextbox" TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonFalseBackground" Color="{StaticResource Color.Additional.LightGrey}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonTrueBackground" Color="{Binding ParentTemplate.Background}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonFalseForeground" Color="{StaticResource Color.Additional.MediumGrey}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleButtonTrueForeground" Color="{StaticResource Color.MedtronicBranding.MedtronicBlue}" />

            <Style x:Key="OnContentControl" TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBlock
                                    FontSize="8"
                                    Foreground="White"
                                    Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonContentTextbox}"
                                    Text="ON" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="OffContentControl" TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBlock
                                    FontSize="8"
                                    Foreground="White"
                                    Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonContentTextbox}"
                                    Text="OFF" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>

        </Style.Resources>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Grid x:Name="MainRow">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=TopRow, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=TopRow, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition x:Name="TopRow" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Ellipse
                                    x:Name="BackgroundEllipse1"
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                    Width="{Binding ElementName=MainRow, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                    Height="{Binding ElementName=MainRow, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Fill="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
                            <Ellipse
                                    x:Name="BackgroundEllipse2"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                    Width="{Binding ElementName=MainRow, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                    Height="{Binding ElementName=MainRow, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    Fill="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}, AncestorLevel=1}}"/>
                            <Border
                                    x:Name="BackgroundBorder"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Background="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="AnimationWidth" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=MainRow, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="AnimationSizeBorder" Grid.Column="0" />
                            <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource OnContentControl}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=MainRow, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource OffContentControl}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <StackPanel
                                    Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Border Width="{Binding ElementName=AnimationSizeBorder, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                                <Ellipse
                                        x:Name="ForegroundEllipse"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"              
                                        Width="15"
                                        Height="15"
                                        Fill="{StaticResource ToggleButtonTrueForeground}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ForegroundEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="White" />
                            <Setter TargetName="AnimationSizeBorder" Property="Width" Value="0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
 <ToggleButton               
                Width="50"
                Height="25"  
                Margin="0,10,0,0"
                IsChecked="False"
                Background="BlueViolet"   
                Style="{StaticResource OnOffToggleButton}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

**Converters**

```
 public class SumHeightConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var firstValue = (object)values[0];
            var secondValue = (object)values[1];
            var value = ((double)15 * (double)firstValue) / (double)25;

            double _Sum = 0;

            if (firstValue != null && secondValue != null)
            {
                _Sum = value;
            }

            return _Sum;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class SumWidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double _Sum = 0;

            var firstValue = (object)values[0];
            var secondValue = (object)values[1];
            var value = ((double)15 * (double)firstValue) / (double)50;

            if (firstValue != null && secondValue != null)
            {
                _Sum = value;
            }


            return _Sum;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

[image: Toggle Button] [[image: After updating Width and Height screenshot]][2
[image: Width and Height={TemplateBinding Height} screenshot]

Comment: I don't understand. How do you want to det the size of the ForegroundEllipse? What is firstValue and secondValue in your converters?

Comment: @mm8, Please refer my updated screenshot. When I change the height and width it look like this. That's why I used converters to change the ForegroundEllipse with respect to user give height and width. But it is not working. Give any suggestion to fix this.

Comment: How do you expect it to look then?

Comment: @mm8, When User change the Height and width of the toggle button, the foregroundEllipse aslo change that is my requirement.

Comment: So bind the `Width` and `Heigh`t to the corresponding properties of the `Button`, e.g.: `Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"`?

Comment: @mm8 When I set Width={TemplateBinding Width} the ForegroundEllipse size is not correct see my screenshot attached.

Comment: It's still unclear what "correct" actually means in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178082/discussion-between-achu-l-and-mm8).